# PHP Laravel Framework - How to delete a table/model using appzcoder crud-generator

Tags: php, laravel, crud-admin-generator

I am using https://github.com/appzcoder/crud-generator to generate CRUDs for setup tables. When use the command

`php artisan crud:generate Posts --fields_from_file="/path/to/fields.json" --view-path=admin --controller-namespace=Admin --route-group=admin`

It generates model/controller/views/migrations for the provided table name. Is there any command with which I can delete everything (model/controller/views/migrations) related to the table name?

Comment: On docs there's nothing about deleting it, so I guess you need to do it manually.

Comment: Yes there is nothing about deleting, hence I did it manually, but I am not sure if there remains any hidden 'effects' which may cause trouble later.